# how to extract specific content from dataframe based on condition python

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following pandas dataframe:
[image]

this is an example of ingredients_text :

> farine de blé 34% (france), pépites de chocolat 20g (ue) (sucre, pâte de cacao, beurre de cacao, émulsifiant lécithines (tournesol), arôme) (cacao : 44% minimum), matière grasse végétale (palme), sucre, 8,5% chocolat(sucre, pâte de cacao, cacao et cacao maigre en poudre) (cacao: 38% minimum), 5,5% éclats de noix de pécan (non ue), poudres à lever : diphosphates   carbonates de sodium, blancs d’œufs, fibres d'acacia, lactose et protéines de lait, sel.   dont lait.

> oignon 18g oil hell: kartoffelstirke, milchzucker, maltodextrin, reismehl. 100g produkt enthalten: 1559KJ ,energie 369 kcal  lt;0.5g  lt;0.1g 909 fett davon gesättigte fettsāuren kohlenhydrate davon ,zucker 26g

I separated the ingredients of each line into words with the folowing code :

```
for i in df['ingredients_text'][:].index:
        words = df["ingredients_text"][i].split(',')
        df["ingredients_text"][i]=words
```

Any idea of how to extract the ingredients with % and g from the text in onether column called 'ingredient' ?
For instance, the desired output should be:

```
['farine de blé 34%', 'pépites de chocolat 20g','cacao : 44%' ,'8,5% chocolat' ,'cacao: 38%', '5,5% éclats de noix de pécan']
['oignon 18g oil hell', '100g produkt enthalten', 'lt;0.5g', 'lt;0.1g' , '26g zucker']
```

Comment: What if g is present in the ingredient but it doesn't really represent grams, like in `'ginger'`?

Comment: g need to be with a digit number like 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ingredient_text': ['a%bgC, abc, a%, cg', 'xyx']})

      ingredient_text
0  a%bgC, abc, a%, cg
1                 xyx
```

Split the ingredients into a list

```
df['ingredient_text'] = df['ingredient_text'].str.split(',')
           ingredient_text
0  [a%bgC,  abc,  a%,  cg]
1                    [xyx]
```

Search for your strings in the list

```
df['ingredient'] = df['ingredient_text'].apply(lambda x: [s for s in x if ('%' in s) or ('g' in s)])

           ingredient_text         ingredient
0  [a%bgC,  abc,  a%,  cg]  [a%bgC,  a%,  cg]
1                    [xyx]                 []
```

Comment: thank you for your help it works for % but it doesn't work for the ingredients with g (gram) . Can you help me please ? ==> df['ingredient'] = df['ingredients_text'].apply(lambda x: [s for s in x if ('\d+\s*g' in s) or ('%' in s)])

Comment: You can `import re` and use `[s for s in x if ('%' in s) or (len(re.findall('\d+g', s))>0)]`